# struts2 json do not return value from a variable

Tags: json, struts2, struts, struts-config

I am doing my struts project now i want to retrieve data as json. But the variable that i want to get the json response does'nt retrieve the json values that i need.

Here is my Action class

```
import com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.Doctor;
import com.myDrDirect.order.dao.DoctorDashBoardDao;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class patientOrderDetails extends ActionSupport {
    private int rows;
    private int total;
    private int records;
    private int page;
    private List recentOrders;
    public String jsonRecentOrderDetails() {

         try{
            Map sessionSingleDoctor = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
            Doctor SessionObj = (Doctor) sessionSingleDoctor.get("Doctor");

          records = DoctorDashBoardDao.getInstance().getCount();
            //records = 10;
             setRows(Integer.parseInt(getText("number.rows.per.page")));
        //rows = 10;
            int to = (getRows() * getPage());
            int from = (getRows() * (getPage()-1));


            total =(int) Math.ceil((double)records / (double)rows);   
            recentOrders= DoctorDashBoardDao.getInstance().getDoctorRecentOrderDetails(rows,from,SessionObj.getId());


     } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
            //log.error("Error occured " + e.toString());
            return ERROR;
        }
          return SUCCESS;
     }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(int rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(int page) {
        this.page = page;
    }

    public int getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(int records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List getRecentOrders() {
        return recentOrders;
    }

    public void setRecentOrders(List recentOrders) {
        this.recentOrders= recentOrders;
    }


}
```

and my struts.xml have

```
<package name="json" extends="json-default">

            <action name="DashBoardActivityJson" class="com.myDrDirect.doctor.action.patientOrderDetails" method="jsonRecentOrderDetails">
                <result name="success" type="json">
                    <!-- serialize the result property of the action -->                    
                    <param name="includeProperties">recentOrders</param>

                </result>
            </action>
            <action name="grid" >
                <result name="success" >/WEB-INF/doctor/jsonGrid.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
```

I need to get the response in `RecentOrders1` varable but this variable not retrieve the json data. When i retrieve the variable `records` i got the response correctly. The recorde only have a totalcount of the list but the recentOrder1 returns a list. I need to get the recentOrder as list in my view page. Can anybody please tell me what is the issue in the above action or xml file. Please help.

One thing i have noticed here is return value in recentOrder is a list. Do i need to convert this list to json string. Is it necessary or struts2 automatically change my list variable into a json string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action doesn't have a property `RecentOrders1`, only `recentOrders`.

Note both the capitalization, and lack of a digit.

Comment: thanks for the immediate reply. I have change the variable name **RecentOrders1**  to **recentOrders** and write the getter and setter for this. Also i have change my struts.xml result type like this **<param name="includeProperties">recentOrders</param>**. But i can't view the result. There is a slight change in the result now result showing like {"recentOrders":[]}. What may be the issue

Comment: It's an empty list. Verify it has content.

Comment: when i print recentOrders the console print the result like this com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1868e75 com.myDrDirect.hbmobj.PatientOrder@1aa89eb. Data is there, but it cannot seen in view page

Comment: @user359187 Verify the result using Firebug/Chrome debugging tools; see what's coming back on the wire. You can also use the `"root"` param to set the list to be the only object returned.

Comment: Do i need to change my list to a json String. In the page http://blog.theunical.com/java/struts2-json-to-achieve-the-return-of-objects-and-a-list-of-ajax/ they are mention like that.

Comment: @user359187 No, the JSON plugin serializes objects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7390/discussion-between-user359187-and-dave-newton)

Comment: I think there is no proper solution for my problem. May be i have to do some other pagination component in struts2 other than struts2 jquery datagrid.

Comment: @user359187 You may proceed as you wish, but the JSON plugin works fine, and serializes lists without a problem. I can't help you more because you're not providing requested information or following up with the results of examining the request. I don't even know what version of S2 you're using.

Comment: I am using struts2 and plugin i use struts2-jqury-datagrid. The jar file i used are struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.1.1.jar,struts2-jquery-plugin-2.4.0.jar,struts2-json-plugin-2.2.3.jar,struts2-core-2.2.1.jar. I can provide you more information if you need.

Comment: @user359187 ... You know that both S2 and the jQuery plugin have versions, right?